# Fourier-Motzkin Elimination

Tags: plotting

Is there any method available in mathematica to eliminate variable from set of inequalities? I tried Eliminate function available, but I guess it works on equalities only.

Comment: Please add an example that you used with `Eliminate` that didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'll borrow an example from another response. Recast as an existance problem in the variable you want to eliminate, then use Resolve.

```
sol = 
 Resolve[Exists[y, 
   And @@ {x >= 4 y, x <= 3 + 4 y, x >= 0, x <= 63, y >= 0, y <= 15}]]

(* x \[Element] 
  Reals && ((-3 + x <= 0 && -x <= 0) || (-60 + x <= 0 && -x <= 
      0) || (-63 + x <= 0 && 3 - x <= 0) || (-63 + x <= 0 && 
     60 - x <= 0)) *)
```

Comment: I think it is still a little bit different from FME, FME only gives you the min <= x <= max, which you eliminates y and leave x.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at `Reduce` :

```
sol = Reduce[{x >= 4 y, x <= 3 + 4 y, x >= 0, x <= 63, y >= 0, y <= 15}, {y}, Integers] ;
```

You can then build a function with :

```
ysol[x_] =  Piecewise[Transpose[{sol[[All, 2, 2]] /. Or -> List, 
                                 sol[[All, 1]] /. Or -> List}]];

DiscretePlot[ysol[x], {x, 0, 63}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I feed this {x >= 4 y, x <= 3 + 4 y, x >= 0, x <= 63, y >= 0, y <= 15} and it says Eliminate::eqf: "y<=15 is not a well-formed equation" what does it mean?

Comment: What output are you trying to get ?

Comment: I want to eliminate variable y from above inequalities..

Comment: Isn't there a single simple method to remove a variable for system of inequalities
???/

Comment: If the solution provided by Daniel Lichtblau is not what you want please say why.

Comment: When I input this snippet to Mathematica it is printing empty plot.

Comment: What are you trying to plot ? Is it visualizing the x intervals where the set of inequalities is satisfied ?